# How to if else condition in Jenkins parameterized pipeline if parameter value match then trigger the job other then not

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, amazon-ecr

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccZCk.png)
how to fetch this value in Jenkins declarative pipeline and if value match then trigger the job and ECR tag was fetch in ECR repo then how to implement
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylHfM.png) so if tag pass using api http://jenkins:8080/job/Nm/buildWithParameters?ECR_TAG=0.1.3 then its give error and if pass in Jenkins URL tag=0.1.1 or 0.1.2 then success but tag name auto increment

Answer (score 0):

You can use `when`, expression under stage, under this `when` condition you can check if the env parameter is true or false.

```
pipeline {
agent {
    node {
        label 'master'
    }
}
options {
    timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS', activity: true)  // abort if nothing happens on  the console for 1h
    timestamps()  // prepend timestamps on the console output
}

parameters {
choice(name: 'ECR_TAG', choices: ['0.1.1', '0.1.2', '0.1.3'], description: 'TAG for ECR')
}
stages {
    stage('Git Checkout') {
        when {
            expression { env.ECR_TAG == "0.1.1" }
        }
        steps {
            script{
            // your script here.
            echo "Hello"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}//pipeline

Above pipeline stage will be executed only when you have given the `ECR_TAG` parameter value as `0.1.1` while triggering your job.

Comment: If a ECR tag was fetch in ECR repo and its multiple then how to implement ? and also attach my jenkins pipeline pipeline {
agent any

stages {
     stage ('Docker Stop') {

        steps {
            
          ///Script///
        }
    }
 stage ("wait_for_removal")
{
    steps{
   ////
}
}
    stage ('Docker start') {

        steps {
            
          ////
        }
    }
  }
}

Comment: if multiple values for parameters needed then you can use Choice Parameter. I have modified answer accordingly.